# How to handle Primary/Secondary/Normal statuses for entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, relationship, entities

I am developing an application and I came across the following: Lets say I have an entity called Contact, that Contact belongs to a Company and the Company has a Primary Contact and a Secondary Contact and also has the remaining Contacts which I've named Normal.

My question is, what is the best approach for this when talking about entities properties and also form handling. I've though about two things:

1. Having 2 fields on the Company entity called PrimaryContact and SecondaryContact and also have a one-to-many relationship to a property called contacts.

What I don't like (or I'm not 100% how to do) about this option is that on the Contact entity I would need an inversedBy field for each of the 2 one-to-one properties and also 1 for the one-to-many relationship and my personal thought is that this is kind of messy for the purpose.

2. Having a property on the Contact entity called Type which would hold if it's primary, secondary or normal and in the Company methods that has to do with Contacts I would modify it and add the getPrimaryContact, getSecondaryContact, etc.

What I don't like about this option is that I would need to have 2 unmapped properties for the Company and I would need to do a lot on the form types in order to get this to work smoothly.

My question is what is the best approach for this structure and how to deal with forms and these dependencies. Let me know if this is not clear enough and I will take time and preparate an example with code and images.

Comment: Your second approach is probable the best.  Forms win't be a problem as long getPrimaryContact/getSecondaryContract methods are defined.  Forms don't need actual properties when you have getter/setters defined.

Comment: So I don't need a unmapped property in the company called primaryContact? In this case I would just need to implement those methods and loop through the contacts and find the one I need?

Comment: I just tested my second approach with the tips you gave me. I didn't know how to manage this kind of mappings which didn't belong to the database, you saved me a lot of trouble! worked perfectly!!!. 

should I answer my own question with what I did?

Comment: Glad it is working.  Go ahead and answer your own question.  I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cerad this is the following approach I took:

1. I have a OneToMany property on the Company to hold all the contacts.
2. Implemented the getPrimaryContact/setPrimaryContact methods and looped through all the contacts and retrieving the one of the type I want. Did the same for the secondary.
3. On the Form type of the company my issue was that I had the 'mapped' => 'false' option, I removed this since I implemented the getters and setters SF2 knows it has to go to these methods.

`

```
<?php

namespace XYZ\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Company
{
    ... 
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\XYZ\Entity\Contact", mappedBy="company", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $contacts;

    public function getPrimaryContact() { ... }
    public function setPrimaryContact(Contact $contact) { //Set the type of $contact and add it $this->addContact($contact) }
    public function getSecondaryContact() { ... }    
    public function setSecondaryContact(Contact $contact) { //Set the type of $contact and add it $this->addContact($contact) }

}`
```

And for the Form Type I have:

`

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ...
            ->add('primaryContact', new ContactType())
            ->add('secondaryContact', new ContactType())
    }

    ...
}`
```

With this set everything runs smoothly and I can CRUD without much struggle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet a Symfony expert but i'm currently learning entites manipulation and relations !
And there is not simple way to do relations with attributes.

You have to create an entity that represent your relation.

Let's suppose you have an entity Company and and entity Contact

Then you will have an entity named **CompanyContact** whick will represent the relation between your objects. (you can have as many attributes as you wish in your relation entity). (Not sure for the Many-to-One for your case but the idea is the same)

```
<?php

namespace My\Namespace\Entity

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Namespace\Entity\CompanyContactRepository")
 */
class CompanyContact
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="contact_type", type="string", length=255)
   */
  private $contactType;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\Namespace\Entity\Company")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  private $company;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\Namespace\Entity\Contact")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  private $contact;

}
```

And in your controller you can do this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$company            = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Company')->find($yourCompanyId);
$yourType           = "primary";
$companyContacts    = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:CompanyContact')
                         ->findBy(array('company' => $company, 'type' => $yourType));
```

What do you think about this approach ?
If i learn more soon i will get you posted ;)

Comment: I recommend only the idea, not really the code posted. I'm stille in learning phase and it seems findBy is not a recommended way of dealing with realations between entities. I will propably delete my answer. Thanks for the edit suggested btw

Comment: this is a workaround that could work. However, I am trying to avoid having too much code/files for this since I believe it can be achieved without having a third entity. On the long road (if you have more relationships like this) you will end up with another file per relationship and also you will need to write more code to handle the forms properly. As for a property Type in the Contact entity would take care of this. But this workaround would work. Also, I'm not sure performance-wise how Symfony2 would take having this entity in the middle for every relationship

Comment: @Ben - the problem with your design is that a given contact can only belong to one and only one business.  The ManyToMany approach described above allows the same contact to be primary for some stuff and secondary for others.